# Method level scope of variables

Tags: java, variables, methods, scope

I am a beginner in Java and came across these errors while practicing, so I thought of clarifying them instead of trying to memorize the error to avoid them.

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if(a > b) {
    int result = a % b;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This generates me `a cannot find symbol`, but I thought I initialize the result as `int` in the `if` loops?

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if(a > b) {
    int result = a % b;
    return result;
  }
}
```

For this, if I return the result in the if loop, is it wrong because it continues looping?

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
  int result = 0;
  if(a > b) {
    result = a % b;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The error goes away on declaring result outside of the `if` loop. Why is that?

Comment: Also if is not a loop. It's a condition. A loop is a construct that allows you to repeat an operation a number or desired times...

Answer (score 4):

This is related to the scope of the variable `result`. When it was inside the `if` it stopped existing when you left the `if` (the `}`).

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b){
    int result = 0;
    if (a > b) {
        result = a % b;
    }
    return result;
} // result exists until here

public static int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (a > b) {
        int result = a % b;
    } // result exists until here
    return result; // result doesn't exist in this scope
}
```

Basically you can only access variables within the blocks of code where they are defined, a block of code is defined by curly braces `{ ... }`.

An alternative implementation of your function could be done without the variable at all.

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (a > b) {
        return a % b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2148463 no problems, make sure you close off the question by hitting the tick.

Comment: @Tyriar, that is not called *closing* in stackoverflow, but *accepting an answer*. The question is still open after it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are called *local* because they can only be seen inside the *block* they were created in.

A block is any code inside `{ ... }`.

Let's see the blocks you have in your first version:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) { // first block starts here
  if(a>b) { // second block, an inner block, starts here
      int result=a%b;
  } // second block ends here
  return result;
} // first block ends here
```

So, you create a local variable in the *second* block, and try to use it *outside* that block, ie, in the *first* block. That's what the compiler is complaining about. The variable `result` kind of disappeared after the *second* block finished.

Comment: But this variable result i am creating,i only want them inside the if loops.So i create inside the if loops.

Comment: @user2148463 If you create variables inside if loop. It won't be accessible outside of that loop.

Comment: Actually, you **do want it** outside the `if` block, since you are *returning* it from outside the `if` block. In other words, you are accessing it from an outer block, that outer block needs to know the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the first error is that the `if` statement establishes a new context for variables. The declaration of `result` is not visible outside the body of the `if`.

In the second case, the `if` condition may fail to be satisfied, in which case the function will not execute a `return` statement. That is also an error, because the function needs to return an `int` (or throw an exception) for every execution path.